# how to write a recursive process into a .txt file?

Tags: recursion

anyone can help me how to write the process of the recursive process into a .txt file??

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int ack(int m,int n){
if(m==0){
         cout<<n<<"+1"<<endl;
         return n+1;
         }
         else if((m!=0) && (n==0)){
              cout<<"a("<<m<<"-1,1)"<<endl;
              return ack(m-1,1);
              }
              else if((m!=0) && (n!=0)){
                   cout<<"a("<<m<<"-1,a("<<m<<","<<n<<"-1)"<<endl;
                   return ack(m-1,ack(m,n-1));
                   }
                   }                       
int main(){
cout<<ack(3,4)<<endl<<endl;
system("pause");   
}
```

i've tried this

```
ofstream filestream("filename..txt");
```

but it only write the result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are better ways to do it, but I find this one simpler:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

ofstream file("filename.txt");
int ack(int m, int n){
    if (m == 0){
        file << n << "+1" << endl;
        return n + 1;
    }
    else if ((m != 0) && (n == 0)){
        file << "a(" << m << "-1,1)" << endl;
        return ack(m - 1, 1);
    }
    else if ((m != 0) && (n != 0)){
        file << "a(" << m << "-1,a(" << m << "," << n << "-1)" << endl;
        return ack(m - 1, ack(m, n - 1));
    }
}
int main(){
    file << ack(3, 4) << endl << endl;
    system("pause");
}
```

Another way would be to pass the file handler as an argument. This helps avoiding the global I used, but requires a little bit more changes to your code to pull off.